# term of art for extra-shallow-depth refrigerator

Tags: remodeling, terminology

I am hoping to replace an old fridge with a new one that does not stand so far out from the wall. I've found so-called "counter-depth" ones that are about 30" deep  and also a few models that are about 25" deep. The latter were found by accident using no search-term in particular other than "refrigerator", which returns gazillions. Is there a term-of-art for extra-shallow-depth refrigerators that could be used to find others like those?

Comment: What terms have you used that are leaving you without the desired results? Sharing those will save time for people guessing things that you've already guessed.

Answer (score 3):

I might try "low-profile" also searches that seem successful are: "Counter-depth" and "cabinet depth".

What you could also do is just specifically type in the depth you want, i.e. "24" depth refrigerator".